# Firebase validation - optional property

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My actual validation looks like:

```
  ".write": true,  
   ".validate": "newData.child('name').isString() 
     && newData.child('surname').isString() 
     && newData.child('age').isNumber()",
```

However, the `age` property is **optional**. User can fill it or not, depends on his decision.

My case is, how to say to firebase that `age` is **optional**, but if it is there (user fills it) - it has to be a **number**?

Something like `maybe type` in Flow or TypeScript (`age?: number`)

Thanks!:)

Comment: why not simply set it to `0` in your client side javascript? In other words, `var userAge = 0`.

Comment: @RonRoyston It's a hack. I don't want any hacks :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the age optional, move its validation rule down to the specific value you're trying to validate:

```
".write": true,  
".validate": "newData.child('name').isString()  && newData.child('surname').isString()"
"age": {
  ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
}
```

The reason this works is that validation rules only fire when the data is present, so the validation on `age` only is executed when the age property is present, exactly as you want.

In general I'd recommend to move the type-validations down to the child nodes, and only keep the "these properties must be present" on the higher level:

```
".write": true,  
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'surname'])",
"name": { 
  ".validate": "newData.isString()" 
},
"surname": { 
  ".validate": "newData.isString()" 
},
"age": {
  ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
}
"$other": {
  ".validate": false
}
```

The last validation above ensure that **only** the specified properties are ever allowed, so users can't add other data (that your code may not be equipped to handle).

Comment: Thank you Frank. Just one more little thing - is there any documentation with all possible rules in `validation`, like `isString()`, `isNumber()` and more? I'm looking for such rules as `isArray()` or `isObject()` or `isEmpty()`

Comment: That'd be https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/, but the methods you are looking for don't exist (nor have I found a need for them).

Comment: Didn't find anything about objects, but ive just used `.exists()` and seems like it works fine. However, it doesnt check if object is empty or not, so it's not the best solution :/

Comment: Validation rules are only there to validate if data follows a defined structure. They don't fire if you write an empty value/delete a node. If you want to ensure data doesn't get deleted, you'd do a `".write": "newData.exists()`.

Comment: By the way - I think that `hasChildren` accepts one argument (array of string) and u provided 2 string arguments to it

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. :-)

Comment: Does this mean that name and surname must always be provided? I have an object which is `{ user: string, surname: string, avatar: string }`. Name and surname are provided first then avatar can be changed whenever

Comment: `newData` contains the data as it will exist after the write operation. So this also contains existing data that isn't modified in the operation.